# Loop Issue in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am currently attempting to run a loop in Mathematica which will attempt to insert in position `{i,4}` of the date list the day of the week. For some reason i can't get `dayint` to increase when `date[[i,3]]!=date[[i-1,3]]` and all values of `date[[i,4]]=5`. I would much appreciate any insight available on this issue.

```
In[4]:= n = 344674; dayint = 5;

In[5]:= solardata = 
  Import["U:\\Masters Project\\Hobo \
Data\\SORMS_Landfill_Comparison_Input.csv", "csv"];

In[6]:= date = 
 Table[DateList[{ToString[solardata[[i, 1]]], {"Month", "Day", 
     "YearShort"}}], {i, n}];

In[8]:= date[[1, 4]] = 5;

In[14]:= For[i = 2, i < n + 1, i++, 
 If[date[[i, 3]] == date[[i - 1, 3]], date[[i, 4]] = dayint, 
  If[dayint == 7, dayint = 1, dayint++]; date[[i, 4]] = dayint]];

In[17]:= date;
```

Comment: tough to debug without seeing the data. Can you provide a small data set that reproduces this issue ( like n=3 ... )

Comment: The first three rows from Out[5]:= {{"11/14/2013", 13.3167, 548.95, 63.3193}, {"11/14/2013", 13.3333, 
  473.03, 181.288}, {"11/14/2013", 13.35, 417.35, 226.605}}

Comment: and Out[6]:={{2013, 11, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, {2013, 11, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, {2013, 11, 14, 0,
   0, 0.}}

Comment: The end of the data has date[[n,4]]=5 even though I know it should be 2 (a Monday) on July 24, 2014.

Comment: I also checked other dates as well. All 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work ok.

```
n = 3; dayint = 5;

date = {
   {2013, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0.},
   {2013, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0.},
   {2013, 12, 01, 0, 0, 0.}};

For[i = 2, i < n + 1, i++,
  If[date[[i, 3]] == date[[i - 1, 3]],
   date[[i, 4]] = dayint,
   If[dayint == 7, dayint = 1, dayint++];
   date[[i, 4]] = dayint]];

date
```

> {{2013, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0.}, {2013, 11, 30, 5, 0, 0.}, {2013, 12, 1, 6, 
>     0, 0.}}

**Edit**

Perhaps you have missing dates?

```
date = {
   {2013, 11, 28, 0, 0, 0.},
   {2013, 11, 29, 0, 0, 0.},
   {2013, 11, 29, 0, 0, 0.},
   {2013, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0.},
   {2013, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0.},
   {2013, 12, 01, 0, 0, 0.}};

dates = Union@date;
{mindate, maxdate} = Through[{First, Last}@dates];
days = QuantityMagnitude@DateDifference[mindate, maxdate, "Day"];
If[Length[dates] == days + 1, "All dates included", "There are dates missing"]
```

> All dates included